# Deploying war to production from mac | WinSCP equivalent

Tags: macos, tomcat, war, sftp, winscp

I have a dynamic web project which I run locally on tomcat. We have a linux based production server which is accessed via host, port username and password.

Earlier, I had a windows machine and I used [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) for transferring the war to the `webapp` folder of tomcat in linux machine. But now, we have got a mac machine to work and I am unable to find a similar way(or any other easier) to deploy my application war onto the production.

What is the best way to deploy the war in the above mentioned scenario? I am unable to find any WinSCP equivalent for mac and also don't know the use of any other `SFTP client` to be used in mac.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to find any WinSCP equivalent for mac and also don't know the use of any other SFTP client to be used in mac.

"Equivalent"?

If you're using WinSCP on Windows, why not use `scp`, the command-line tool that ships with OS X?

Comment: I am somehwhat noob when it comes to using MAC. Do you have any guidelines or steps or something which could help me out. I would then write a POC for the same so that it may help others as well.